# Completeness of a metric space with the Hausdorff metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(Y,d)$  be a metric space and let $K(Y)$ denote the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $Y$. This collection is a metric space when equipped with the Hausdorff distance $h$.

I want to prove that
$(Y,d)$ being complete implies that $(K(Y),h)$ is complete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309827/completeness-of-the-hausdorff-distance) question, in suffices to show that $K(Y)$ is closed in $F(Y)$. Since a subset of a complete metric space is compact iff it is closed and totally bounded, for this purpose it suffices to show that a limit $A$ (in $F(Y)$) of a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of non-empty compact subsets of $Y$ is totally bounded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if $(E,d)$ is complete then, $(\mathcal{K}(E), \mathcal{H})$ is also complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493757/prove-that-if-e-d-is-complete-then-mathcalke-mathcalh-is-also)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309827/completeness-of-the-hausdorff-distance

Comment: @user357151 No. It's not a time traveler. The link you gives is dated by 2017, the question here was asked in 2013.