# Proof of completeness of the space of compact subspaces.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

> Let $(X, p)$ be a compact space with metric $p$. Let $H(X) = \{A \subset X | A=[A]\}$, $p'= max_{a \in A} min_{b \in B} (p(a, b)) + max_{b \in B} min_{a \in A} ((a, b))$. Prove that $(H(X), p')$ is complete metric space.

I've already understood how to prove that $p'$ is metric. But I have question about how to prove its completeness. I think I should use the theorem about completeness of a metric space (A metric space X is complete if and only if every decreasing sequence of non-empty closed subsets of X, with diameters tending to 0, has a non-empty intersection)

Comment: By $[A]$ do you mean the closure of $A$?

Comment: I think you'll find that for a Cauchy sequence $\{A_n\}$, the set $L = \{ x \in X\mid (\exists n)(\forall k > n)(x \in A_k)\}$ will serve as a limit.

Comment: In general, a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. So this question is a bit superfluous.

Comment: See answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309827/completeness-of-the-hausdorff-distance) question.

Comment: @Demophilus yes

Comment: @PaulSinclair but how to prove that $L$ is closed?

Comment: @PaulSinclair i've tried to prove that its closed: $X$ is compact, so L is covered with union of $A_k$, for $k>=0$. So we can get a finite subcover. Finite union of closed sets is closed.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulSinclair and showint that L is limit isn't obvious.  $\forall \epsilon > 0,\exists N=N(\epsilon), \forall m, n > N, p(A_m, A_n) < \epsilon$ how do I prove from this that $p(L, A_n) = max_{l \in L} min_{a_n \in A_n} p(l, a_n) + max_{a_n \in A_n} min_{l \in L} p(l, a_n) < \epsilon$

Comment: Concerning your argument that $L$ is closed: you are missing 2 things: Compactness only guarantees that covers by *open* sets have finite subcovers. And, it is $X$ that is known to be compact and so has this property. If we knew $L$ was compact, then there would be nothing more to prove as compactness implies closed in metric spaces.

Comment: And concerning the limit, note that if $l\in L$, then there exists $m > N$ such that $l \in A_m$.