# In what metric spaces is the intersection of nested closed sets non-empty?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I know that in a complete metric space, if $F_1\supseteq F_2\supseteq...$ are closed, and $\text{diam}(F_n)\to0,$ then $\bigcap\{F_n\}\not=\emptyset.$ John B. Conway claims falsely that even if $\text{diam}(F_N)\not=0,$ but is still bounded for all $n$, then $\bigcap\{F_n\}\not=\emptyset.$ I say he claims it falsely as we can conisder
$$F_n=\{n,n+1,n+2,...\}$$ 
as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete metric, in which case $F_n$ is trivially closed and bounded, since discrete, but $\bigcap\{F_n\}=\emptyset.$

Now, I am curious if there are conditions we can add to Conway's statement to make it correct? What requirements would we need on a metric space to guarantee that for all bounded closed sets $F_1\supseteq F_2\supseteq...$ we would have $\bigcap\{F_n\}\not=\emptyset$?

Comment: @saulspatz I missed that we are dealing with the discrete metric here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sets were closed and totally bounded in a complete metric space then it would be correct. As you've shown, merely bounded is not enough, but if they're totally bounded then they are compact, and hence the intersection is nonempty.

In the usual metric on $\mathbb R^n$, all bounded subsets are totally bounded. If the metric has this property, then the statement is correct.

Comment: Are there metric spaces without the Heine-Borel property were this would hold, or is it necessary?

Comment: @Melody If there is any closed and bounded subset that is not compact, then you can find a counterexample. I think this might actually characterize it.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @Melody You're welcome.

Comment: @Melody I've reverted my claim that it's equivalent to the Heine-Borel property, but the original answer stands. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3106782/187867