# Is the Hausdorff distance a metric on the set of closed bounded subsets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and define for a bounded set $A\subset X$ and a point $x\in X$ the distance from $x$ to $A$ by
$$
r(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a):a\in A\}.
$$
Define for closed bounded sets $A,B\subset X$ the *Hausdorff distance*
$$
h(A,B) = \max\left\{\sup_{a\in A}r(a,B), \sup_{b\in B}r(A,b)\right\}.
$$
The book I am using, [Elementary Topology Problem Textbook](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/eng-book-nopfs.pdf), asks to prove that $h$ is a metric on the set $\mathcal K = \{A\subset X: A \text{ closed and bounded}\}$. I have two problems with this. First, if $A=\varnothing$ then for any $x\in X$ we have $r(x,A)=\inf\varnothing = +\infty$, so clearly $h$ cannot be a metric. This can be remedied by considering $\mathcal K = \{A\subset X: A \text{ closed, bounded, and nonempty}\}$.

My second concern is that $\mathcal K$ should really be $\{A\subset X: A \text{ compact}\}$. To show the triangle inequality for $h$, we first need the triangle inequality for $\rho$, where $\rho(A,B) = \sup_{a\in A}r(a,B)$. For this we need the property that for each $x\in X$ and $A\in\mathcal K$ there exists $a_x\in A$ such that $r(x,A)=d(x,a_x)$. In [this paper](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/SeniorProject_KatieBarich.pdf), this is Property (3) of Theorem 1. The proof given relies on sequential compactness (which is equivalent to compactness in metric spaces).

Do we need to limit $\mathcal K$ to compact sets, or is it okay to define it on (nonempty) closed bounded sets, in order for $h$ to be a metric?

Comment: can't you pick any $a\in A$ so that $r(x,A)\approx d(x,a)$ and proceed from there

Comment: What do you mean by $r(x,A)\approx d(x,a_x)$ exactly?

Comment: take any $\varepsilon>0$, take $a\in A$ with $r(x,A)\le d(x,a)<r(x,A)+\varepsilon$

Comment: @Mirko And from there can we conclude the triangle inequality for $\rho$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309827/completeness-of-the-hausdorff-distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with the Hausdorff distance, its better to work with a metric space where $d\le 1$. In principle, this is not a problem, since every metirc space is homeomorphic to one where the metric is bounded.

Given this modification, we can define, for *arbitrary* subsets of $X$,

$$
h(A,B):=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } A=B=\emptyset\\
1 & \text{if exactly one of $A$ and $B$ is $\emptyset$}\\
\max\left\{\sup_{a\in A}r(a,B), \sup_{b\in B}r(A,b)\right\}& \text{if }A\neq\emptyset \wedge B\neq\emptyset
\end{cases}
$$
Then you can show that $h$ is a pseudo metric on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the key being the inequality:
$$
d(x,Y)≤d(x,Z)+h(Y,Z)
$$
where we define $d(x,\emptyset)=1$.

You can also prove that $h(A,B)=0\iff \bar A=\bar B$, which shows that $h$ is a metric on the family of closed sets.

When dealing with compact sets, you get easier proofs of the facts above, together with many extra properties. See I.4.F in Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*

Comment: The boundedness part can be taken care of by using $\overline d = \max\{d,1\}$, I suppose. But $h(A,B)=0\iff \overline A=\overline B$ doesn't show that $h$ is a metric, only a pseudometric.

Comment: @Math1000 It shows it's a metric when you restrict to the family of *closed* sets

Comment: You mean, it shows it is a *metric* when you restrict to the family of closed sets?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, sorry about that!

Comment: I see, so the motivation in restricting $\mathcal K$ to compact sets is in e.g. the results "if $(X,d)$ is complete then $(\mathcal K, h)$ is complete" and "if $(X,d)$ is compact then $(\mathcal K, h)$ is compact."

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. You also get, for example, $\mathcal{K}$ Polish if $X$ is Polish, which might not be true for mere closed sets (I'm honestly not sure). Polishness (is that a word?) is really the key concept here. The more useful structure imposed on the family of closed sets is that of a measurable space, look up the Effros-Borel structure in Kechris. All of this stuff has surprising applications too. For example, the hyperspace of compact sets pops up when looking (very finely) at trigonometric series.